# CouchDB - how to grab output for just the map function not the reduce

Tags: couchdb

I have a CouchDB with a view that lists a map function and a reduce function. I'd like to query just the output of the map function (keys and values), can I do that? How?

Answer (score 4):

Apparently you just add ?reduce=false as a query parameter

`https://mycouchdbdomain.com/db/_design/doc/_view/viewname?reduce=false`

Comment: It should be noted that if your view has a reduce defined, it will assume `reduce=true`. If there is no reduce defined, it assumes `reduce=false`